# Is it possible to pass the sum of a column from an HTML table on a DIFFERENT website to a db?

Tags: php, html, html-table

This question probably was worded more complicating than it actually is.

So, basically I am trying to find the "total of column Z" based on reports given to a different website. These reports are given in HTML table form. This website I have no access to. Is it possible, for instance, for me to sum the column of the html table (maybe put in an iframe?) without having access to its source, but while knowing the table ID?

NOTE: I am using HTML, PHP currently (obviously I'm pretty newbie). I don't have much knowledge of java/javascript/jquery, but if it is necessary to complete this task I will learn up! My goal is to send the values of the totals to an Oracle 11g Database, if that makes the problem easier to solve.

I wanted to make sure this is possible before I waste my time trying it. I don't have much time as it is lol.

Example:

Table from "www.website.com"

```
     H1   |  H2  |  H3  |  H4
V1:1 | V1:2 | V1:3 | V1:4
V2:1 | V2:2 | V2:3 | V2:4
V2:1 | V2:2 | V2:3 | V2:4
V2:1 | V2:2 | V2:3 | V2:4
```

My goal:

```
$sum1 = <SUM OF ALL V IN COLUMN H2>;
```

TIA!

Comment: If you don't have access to it, then no.

Comment: *This question probably was worded more complicating than it actually is.* - Yes, the question is somewhat unclear. Could you add example inputs and outputs so that others can get a visual idea of what your goal is?

Comment: So, there is no way for me to grab the totals of a column? Even if I put the table into an iframe, and call its ID when trying to sum?

Comment: Use `curl` or `file_get_contents()` to download the page into a PHP variable, and then use an HTML parser library to get the values from the table.

Comment: @vulcan, I added a basic view of what I need.

Comment: @barmar, that sounds like exactly what I needed. I'll look into how to use those commands :P Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is: "Can I fetch an HTML page, parse its contents, calculate a value from them and save that in a database?" then, Yes, this is possible.

The biggest problem might be getting the contents of another page. I don't think you can easily fetch the contents of an IFrame. Maybe the best solution is to fetch the page in PHP (using curl, for instance).

After that, you can decide whether to do the parsing in PHP as well, or use the more powerful jQuery for that. In case of jQuery you might even run it server side if you have node.js. If you don't, you would have to send the contents to your client for parsing, learn jQuery to parse it, and send it back for storing. Doesn't sound too good. I would keep the parsing server side as well.

Comment: You may have misunderstood, the contents of the other page are NOT in an iframe. They are in a table. I was meaning to ask "If I put <other page> into an iframe, could I easily calculate the sum values from the iframe?" Your answer supports what Barmar commented on OP, very helpful! Thanks :)